# Subtract object's stroke from adjacent objects (to create a border of negative space)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, transparency, stroke

I really don't know how to explain this in words in a simple way, so just take a look at the photo I've linked to below. I have a compound path, and I want to multiply it, but have a "stroke of transparency" around each shape, just like in the image below. How can I do that? I've tried with pathfinder, but I can't get it right.

Thank you!

[image: Black vector-style silhouettes of 3 staggered male figures—one in the foreground, 2 in the background. A border of negative space outlines the forward figure.]

Comment: In this specific instance, you could just stroke it white and then use a "darken only" blend mode when inserting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it: Edit -> Path -> Offset path, which will create a new path that is X pixels bigger/smaller. Afterwards I used that to cut out a hole in the background shape (with the help of pathfinder)